# Custom CSS overide

Tags: theming, panels, upgrading

Is the CSS code entered in the field under "general" on a panel page overridden when a new theme is applied or Drupal is upgraded?

Specifically I am referring to this box.

> [image]

Comment: That is a screenshot from panels right? Since the CSS is stored in the database and injected by panels, I'd be very surprised to learn that it would be affected by theme changes and updates. So (I have never tried), but I don't expect it be. (It would not be very user friendly)